# How to access a random access file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to open a random access file using VB.NET I am getting the following error messge when attempting to access the file `Error 75 (Access to the path ....is denied)`. Is there something that I must change to fix this?

```
Structure StdSections
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Fixed-length string size must fit in the buffer. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="3C1E4426-0B80-443E-B943-0627CD55D48B"'
    <VBFixedString(15), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=15)> Public A() As Char 'BEAM  --- complete beam designation          15
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Fixed-length string size must fit in the buffer. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="3C1E4426-0B80-443E-B943-0627CD55D48B"'
    <VBFixedString(2), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> Public B() As Char 'DSG   --- shape  ie "W" or "C"                2
    Dim C As Single 'DN    --- nominal depth of section            4
    Dim d As Single 'WGT   --- weight                              4
    .
    .
    .
End structure
''Note 'File1' holds complete path!
        Public std As StdSections
        Dim i,ffr,fLength,lastmembNo as integer
        sectionFound = False

        fLength = Len(std)
        If fLength = 0 Then fLength = 168 ' 177
        ffr = FreeFile()
        'FileOpen(ffr, File1, OpenMode.Random, , , fLength)
        FileOpen(ffr, File1, OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockRead, fLength)
        >>Error 75 (Access to the path ....is denied) << path is perfectly good!!!
        lastmembNo = CInt(LOF(ffr)) \ fLength
        'ReDim std(lastmembNo)
        For i = 1 To lastmembNo
            FileGet(ffr, std, i)
               If Trim(memberID) = Trim(std.A) Then
                    sectionFound = True
                end if
        next i
```

Comment: Microsoft didn’t do us a favour when trying to make VB6 like code work in .NET. Rewrite your file access yo use the proper .NET tools – file streams – and parse the fields manually from byte buffers.

Comment: I changed my implementation but I am now getting another error when reading the random access file. I posted a new thread, if you might know what is happening? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452991/how-to-correctly-read-a-random-access-file-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is permissions to the file in question. "Access to the path is denied" doesn't mean the path is bad or invalid, but that you either don't have permission, or the file is locked by another process. Still another possibility is a typo in the path variable (File1 in your sample)

Comment: I changed my implementation but I am now getting another error when reading the random access file. I posted a new thread, if you might know what is happening? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452991/how-to-correctly-read-a-random-access-file-in-vb-net